# Laravel Filtering data between dates

Tags: laravel, filter, controller, laravel-5

I'm beginner in Laravel and web development and I have a silly question, I'm building a system that lists the user financial transactions. In the homepage is listed all the transactions made by the user. I put two fields up there to make the date filter of the transactions, but I don't know how to proceed this filter in Laravel.

I'm using datepicker and it is working fine, I also know that the validation system allows me to use Laravel date: after and date: before, but I don't know how and in which method in the controller send these dates. Here's my dates form code:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'transactions.index']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('data_inicio', 'De: ') !!}
    {!! Form::input('date', 'data_inicio', null, ['class' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'dd/mm/yy']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('data_fim', 'Até: ') !!}
    {!! Form::input('date', 'data_fim', null, ['class' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'dd/mm/yy']) !!}

    {!! Form::submit('Enviar') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The method in the controller which calls the view of the homepage is the index, here's the index code:

```
public function index()
{
    $transactions = Auth::user()->transactions;

    return view('transactions.index', ['transactions' => $transactions]);
}
```

Here is how I show the data in the view:

```
@foreach( $transactions as $transaction )
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">{!! date('d-m-Y', strtotime($transaction->created_at)) !!}</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">{!! $transaction->title !!}</a></td>
        <td>{!! $transaction->amount !!}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I need to send these dates I got to this same method (index) when the Pesquisar button was clicked to be able to seek in the database only the transactions of the proposed date, the problem is I do not know do this.

I tried to send these dates as parameter request to the index method, modifying it like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
```

I got a Column Not Found error when I click in the submit, but I'm not using this request in any query in the method.
I really think that it has a simple way to do it and I appreciate any help!!

Here's my model class:

```
class Transaction extends Model {

    protected $table = 'transactions';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to obtain the dates in your controller:

```
$data_inicio = Input::get('data_inicio');
$data_fim = Input::get('data_fim');
```

Then you can use the dates to query your Transaction relation (assuming this a one to many relationship and is configured propperly)

```
$transactions = Transaction::whereBetween('created_at',[$data_inicio, $data_fim])->where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help!!
I'm having a problem when I press Submit, I got this error:
`QueryException in Connection.php line 620`
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'data_inicio' in 'field list'`
It's trying to find these columns in the database, but I'm not using these dates in any query. I think there's something wrong in the method call or the parameter pass.

Comment: Can you post your model class? in order to see how assign the viariables to the column or columns in your model.

Comment: I posted my model class, I believe the relationship is correct. I tried your way but I dont receive transactions, only the current user. I tried this way:
            `$transactions = Transaction::whereBetween('created_at', array($data_inicio, $data_fim))->get();
        } else {
            $transactions = Auth::user()->transactions;
        }`
  but it returns to me all the transactions, not only of the current user.

Comment: I have a relation very similar, the between you post works very straightforward. Return only the objects between two dates. Must be another problem. Declaration in your User model perhaps?